# Force core to use .dev JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, customization

I was wondering if there's some constant telling WordPress **not** to use the minified versions of scripts but instead load .dev ones. Already tried `define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);` but it only turned off script unification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use a combination of constants on my local install.

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
define('COMPRESS_SCRIPTS', false); // <--- this is likely the one you're after
define('COMPRESS_CSS', false);
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

I'd imagine the second constant listed above is the one you're after.

Comment: Could be me, but that didn't make it. Does it matter where in the wp-config those are dropped in? I put them at the end

Comment: You may need to define them before the require line, mine are placed just before the `$table_prefix` var is set, and it works just fine for me..

Comment: All I needed was to add the 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' and WordPress started using the .dev.js versions.